# Why can't this specific Avenger have children?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> Regarding Natasha Romanoff, AKA Black Widow, Banner rejected Natasha's relationship proposal by saying that he couldn't reproduce (He had kid with an alien in comics, so either MCU changed it or he was lying or he didn't know well about his own mutate body or he wasn't compatible with humans). After that Natasha said that she couldn't reproduce either.

Why can't she become pregnant?

Comment: And this gets downvotes why?

Comment: Because it is explained in the movie. Like literally seconds after she says it. SS is just trolling by asking lots of spoilerish questions.

Comment: Banner wasn't talking about actual reproduction when he said he couldn't reproduce, he was more talking from an aspect of he wouldn't let the Hulk reproduce because that was an unknown he couldn't let into the world.

Comment: Just saw Age of Ultron this weekend.  The audience was filled with small children.  There was a constant stream of adults escorting those children to the restrooms during the movie.  I can totally understand how someone might miss something that is 'like literally seconds' after they left the theatre.  :)

Comment: He’s worried that if he did, hulk wouldn’t allow for it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because as Natasha goes on to explain,

> the final stage of her spy training by the KGB/FSB/unnamed Russian intelligence agency is forced sterilisation, referred to as the Graduation Ceremony in the film. Natasha can't have children because she's been sterilised. Her line 'Still think you're the only monster on  the team?' makes clear that she feels this process has made her a monster/less than human.